# Removing menus from ASP.NET menu

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I'm working on somebody code which left.

This is an ASP.NET WebForm App. For authorizations many roles 
are defined.

He defines a Menu infrastructure on a master page with no MenuItems.

```
 <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />
                            <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" CssClass="noflicker" runat="server"
                                Orientation="Horizontal" StaticDisplayLevels="2" OnMenuItemClick="Menu1_MenuItemClick" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1">
                                <StaticMenuStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                                <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#1e1a53" ForeColor="white" Height="25px" Font-Size="18px" Font-Names="Arial" />
                                <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="14px" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Size="18px" ForeColor="White" Height="25px" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Arial" />
                                <StaticHoverStyle Height="25px" Font-Names="Arial" ForeColor="white" BackColor="#F99D1C" BorderColor="#3366CC" />
                                <DynamicHoverStyle Height="35px" Font-Names="Arial" ForeColor="white" BackColor="#F99D1C" Font-Size="18px" />
                                <DynamicMenuStyle BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="#1e1a53" BorderWidth="1px" Height="25px"
                                    Font-Names="Arial" ForeColor="White" BackColor="#1e1a53" VerticalPadding="3px" />
                                <DynamicSelectedStyle Height="35px" Font-Names="Arial" BorderColor="#1e1a53" BorderWidth="1px" ForeColor="White" BackColor="#1e1a53" />
                                <DynamicMenuItemStyle BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#1e1a53" Height="35px"
                                    ForeColor="White" BackColor="#1e1a53" HorizontalPadding="3px" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="18px"
                                    Font-Names="Arial" CssClass="leftMenuItem" VerticalPadding="5px" ItemSpacing="3px" />
                                <DataBindings>
                                    <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="SiteMapNode" TextField="Title" ToolTipField="description" />
                                </DataBindings>
                            </asp:Menu>
```

The menu gets populated in runtime using sitemap:

```
 SiteMapDataSource1.SiteMapProvider = "allMenuItemsSiteMap";
```

I know if  Menu was defined using Menuitems it was easy to Remove those.

However, using sitemap is there any way to remove an item on the menu?

Currently, the only way I know is to define different sitemaps for different roles, which is definitely not a good solution,

Comment: once it is populated you can loop through the menu (match on menu text?) and remove items - still not an optimal solution

Comment: @Kevin, I think this is better than defining different site maps.

Comment: @kevin , SiteMapDataSource1.SiteMapProvider = "allMenuItemsSiteMap"; does not seem to by itself populate the Menu, Number of items return as 0

Comment: Try Menu1.Items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a C# function, should be easy to convert to vb.net. You would need to change it to be recursive if you have more than two level deep menus.

```
private void RemoveMenuItem(string itemText, Menu menu)
{
   foreach (MenuItem menuItem in menu.Items)
   {
      if (menuItem.Text.Equals(itemText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
      {
           menu.Items.Remove(menuItem);
           break;
      }

      bool found = false;

      if (menuItem.ChildItems.Count > 0) RemoveChildMenuItem(itemText, menuItem, out found);

      if (found) break;
    }
}

private void RemoveChildMenuItem(string itemText, MenuItem mi, out bool Found)
{
      Found = false;

      foreach(MenuItem menuItem in mi.ChildItems)
      {
         if (menuItem.Text.Equals(itemText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            mi.ChildItems.Remove(menuItem);
            Found = true;
            break;
        }                
     }
}
```

Comment: This could be useful but the problem is Menu.Items.Count always shows as 1(only first item).  I try to access the menu on Menu_Prerender event. If this is not correct where else it should be?

Comment: I do it on Page_Load, the menu isn't constructed yet in the Menu_Prerender event

Comment: At least better than using sitemaps!

Comment: glad it helped!